# How to parse groups with operator and brackets

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyparsing

First I would like to say that I am just starting using `pyparsing`, and I need some help with the following. So here is the context:

I have a file with text lines. Each line can have one `sequence` or can be a set of sequences combined with the concurrent operator `||`. The representation can either be `(seq1)||(seq2)||...` etc or simply `seq1`.

A sequence `seq_` is a set of events, starting with a `question` followed by one or more answers, the sequence order is defined by the order of the answers on the line with the operator `->` or `=>` in between. The interpretation is that the system reading the line should execute the `question` and then check that the answers are identical to the ones defined in the line, in the defined order, hence the sequence. The previous definition of a line where several sequences running concurrently simply means that the question at the beginning of each sequence should be executed first and only then the system will check the answers for each question independently (concurrent execution and check).

The `question` format is as such `qtn(elm,sub,num1[,num2,num3,...])` where what is between `[]` is optional and where `elm` and `sub` are names and `num_` are numbers.

The answer is more complicated and can be one of the following:

- `ans(elma,acta,suba,num5[,num6,num7,...][elma.pr1=num8[,elma.pr2=num9]])[<timeout]`, meaning that some `num_` are optional and the timeout too.
- `ans(elma,acta,suba,num5[,num6,num7,...])[<timeout] | prm(elma.pr1=num8[,elma.pr2=num9])` where the `|` operator indicates a `OR`, meaning that one answer `OR`the other is enough to consider that the global answer is correct.
- `ans(elma,acta,suba,num5[,num6,num7,...])[<timeout] & prm(elma.pr1=num)` where the `&` operator indicates a `AND`, meaning that both answers are required to consider that the global answer is correct.
- and of course the answer can be a combination of elements with the `|` and `&` operators mixed in with `()`. For example we could have `ans(elma,acta,suba,num5[,num6,num7,...])[<timeout] | (prm(elma.pr1=num8) & prm(elmb.pr2=num9))` or something more complex with or without `()`. There is no operator priority, only the `()` are indicating some order.

So my idea is to define the general syntax of the different big elements (and I am not sure it is the best way):

- the question would be:

```py
qtn = Regex(r'qtn\([a-z0-9]+,[a-z]+(,[ex0-9_.]+)+\)')
```

- one of the simple answers would be:

```py
ans = Combine(Regex(r'ans\([a-z0-9]+,[a-z]+(,[a-z0-9_.]+)+\)') + Regex('(<[0-9]+)*'))
```

Perhaps it would be better to define separately what a `num` is, what a `timeout` is, what an id such as `elma` is, and compose the answers from those definitions. After having each element of a seq in a list and having the list of all sequences in a line, I am planning to interpret each element in a later part of the code.

Where I am stuck now is on how to define the answer general syntax, which is complex, in such way that the output of parsing can be evaluated according to the `()` and the `&` and the `|` operator. I am trying to understand the `fourFn.py` pyparsing example, but so far I am clueless.

Any help you could give me is welcome.

Comment: fourFn.py is old-school expression parsing. Look at the examples that use infixNotation, it is much simpler to implement your '&' and '|' operators, including precedence and '()'s. And I would definitely do individual Regexes for the different elements, not one for the whole thing. Or even replace things like `Regex(r'[a-z0-9')` with `Word(alphanums)`, depending on your taste for regexen.

Comment: You may also want `Group` instead of `Combine`.

Comment: I am going to look at the `infixNotation` in detail, it seems powerful.

Comment: Thank you @JMW for the edits !

Comment: Sure, no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Regex and sample strings were good inputs for defining a simple parser, usually done a little more formally as a BNF, but these were sufficient. Here is a basic implementation of your simple ans format, you should be able to generalize from here what the question would look like:

```
import pyparsing as pp

LPAR, RPAR, COMMA, LT = map(pp.Suppress, "(),<")

element = pp.Word(pp.alphas.lower(), pp.alphanums.lower())
action = pp.Word(pp.alphas.lower())
subject = pp.Word(pp.alphas.lower())
number = pp.pyparsing_common.number()
timeout_expr = LT + number("timeout")

# put the pieces together into a larger expression
ans_expr = pp.Group(pp.Literal('ans')
                    + LPAR
                    + element('element')
                    + COMMA
                    + action('action')
                    + COMMA
                    + subject('subject')
                    + COMMA
                    + number('num*')
                    + (COMMA + number('num*'))[...]
                    + RPAR
                    + pp.Optional(timeout_expr)
                    )

# use runTests to try it out, will also flag parse errors
ans_expr.runTests("""
    ans(first, act, sub, 1000)
    ans(first, act, sub, 1000, 2000)
    ans(first, act, sub, 1000, 2000) < 50

    # example of a parsing error
    ans(first, act1, sub, 1000)
    """)
```

Will print:

```
ans(first, act, sub, 1000)
[['ans', 'first', 'act', 'sub', 1000]]
[0]:
  ['ans', 'first', 'act', 'sub', 1000]
  - action: 'act'
  - element: 'first'
  - num: [1000]
  - subject: 'sub'

ans(first, act, sub, 1000, 2000)
[['ans', 'first', 'act', 'sub', 1000, 2000]]
[0]:
  ['ans', 'first', 'act', 'sub', 1000, 2000]
  - action: 'act'
  - element: 'first'
  - num: [1000, 2000]
  - subject: 'sub'

ans(first, act, sub, 1000, 2000) < 50
[['ans', 'first', 'act', 'sub', 1000, 2000, 50]]
[0]:
  ['ans', 'first', 'act', 'sub', 1000, 2000, 50]
  - action: 'act'
  - element: 'first'
  - num: [1000, 2000]
  - subject: 'sub'
  - timeout: 50

# example of a parsing error
ans(first, act1, sub, 1000)
              ^
FAIL: Expected ',', found '1'  (at char 14), (line:1, col:15)
```

Note the use of results names to help you access the results by name, which will make your parser easier to maintain and use.

Comment: Thank you for the help. The `runTests()` is giving out printout, however how do I get a structured output from the parsing, such as `dict` with names?

Comment: Go back to using `ans_expr.parseString` to get the actual parsed structure with names. `runTests` is just a wrapper around `result = expr.parseString(a_test_string, parseAll=True)` and `print(result.dump())` or printing a formatted exception explanation. I just got so tired rewriting that stuff for every question I answered online, I just wrote `runTests`.

Comment: Right. I didn't realize that `parseString` is containing a lot more than what is printed when asked to: `([(['ans', 'first', 'act', 'sub', 1000, 2000], {'element': ['first'], 'action': ['act'], 'subject': ['sub'], 'num': [1000, 2000]})], {})` compared to `[['ans', 'first', 'act', 'sub', 1000, 2000]]`. Thanks you!

Comment: `parseString` returns a `ParseResults` object - read more about it here: https://pyparsing-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyparsing.html?highlight=ParseResults#pyparsing.ParseResults

Comment: Thank you! I just noticed that the documentation is under your name... :-(
 
Could you tell me the meaning of the `*` in `number('num*')`, and what is the difference with `number('num')`?

Comment: Try it with and without and see how the returned results change.