# ParseResults output structure with repeating named tokens: how to keep the order in the named dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyparsing

Let's consider the following code I have created, which reflects my issue (following my previous question: [How to parse groups with operator and brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62629424/how-to-parse-groups-with-operator-and-brackets)):

```py
from pyparsing import *

line = 'a(1)->b(2)->c(3)->b(4)->a(5)'

LPAR, RPAR = map(Suppress, "()")
num = Word(nums)
SEQOP = Suppress('->')

a = Group(Literal('a')+LPAR+num+RPAR)('ela*')
b = Group(Literal('b')+LPAR+num+RPAR)('elb*')
c = Group(Literal('c')+LPAR+num+RPAR)('elc*')

element = a | b | c

one_seq_expr = Group(element + (SEQOP + element)[...])('one_seq_expr')

out = one_seq_expr.parseString(line)

print(out.dump())
```

From this code I obtain the following results:

```py
[[['a', '1'], ['b', '2'], ['c', '3'], ['b', '4'], ['a', '5']]]
- one_seq_expr: [['a', '1'], ['b', '2'], ['c', '3'], ['b', '4'], ['a', '5']]
  - ela: [['a', '1'], ['a', '5']]
    [0]:
      ['a', '1']
    [1]:
      ['a', '5']
  - elb: [['b', '2'], ['b', '4']]
    [0]:
      ['b', '2']
    [1]:
      ['b', '4']
  - elc: [['c', '3']]
    [0]:
      ['c', '3']
```

We can access the results in different ways:

```py
>> out[0]
([(['a', '1'], {}), (['b', '2'], {}), (['c', '3'], {}), (['b', '4'], {}), (['a', '5'], {})], {'ela': [(['a', '1'], {}), (['a', '5'], {})], 'elb': [(['b', '2'], {}), (['b', '4'], {})], 'elc': [(['c', '3'], {})]})
>> out['one_seq_expr']
([(['a', '1'], {}), (['b', '2'], {}), (['c', '3'], {}), (['b', '4'], {}), (['a', '5'], {})], {'ela': [(['a', '1'], {}), (['a', '5'], {})], 'elb': [(['b', '2'], {}), (['b', '4'], {})], 'elc': [(['c', '3'], {})]})
>> out['one_seq_expr'][0:4]
[(['a', '1'], {}), (['b', '2'], {}), (['c', '3'], {}), (['b', '4'], {})]
>> for _ in out[0]: print(_)
['a', '1']
['b', '2']
['c', '3']
['b', '4']
['a', '5']
>> out['one_seq_expr']['ela']
([(['a', '1'], {}), (['a', '5'], {})], {})
```

The ParseResults object `out['one_seq_expr']` keeps the order of the different tokens found. On the other hand the structure of the named tokens is grouping them by name and keeps the order of appearance for each name.

Is it possible to obtain an output structure where the order is kept between different elements while keeping the name in a certain form? Something like:

```py
- one_seq_expr: [['a', '1'], ['b', '2'], ['c', '3'], ['b', '4'], ['a', '5']]
  - ela_0: [['a', '1']]
    [0]:
      ['a', '1']
  - elb_0: [['b', '2']]
    [0]:
      ['b', '2']
  - elc_0: [['c', '3']]
    [0]:
      ['c', '3']
  - elb_1: [['b', '4']]
    [0]:
      ['b', '4']
  - ela_0: [['a', '5']]
    [0]:
      ['a', '5']
```

Or do we have to use `ParseResults.getName()` on the ordered list of tokens `out['one_seq_expr']`? Such as:

```py
>> [_.getName() for _ in out['one_seq_expr']]
['ela', 'elb', 'elc', 'elb', 'ela']
```

Comment: I *very* seldom use `getName()` - it was first written to support the deprecated `asXML()` method, which will be dropped in pyparsing 3.0. But this seems like a legitimate use for `getName`, and I think I will add it to the pyparsing unit tests.  In general, think of the results names like keys in a dict, and assigning multiple values to a key will only keep the last value assigned. If you do special names with `listAllMatches=True` or trailing '*', then it is more like a `defaultdict(list)` which will retain multiple values for a key, but lose their respective ordering in the overall list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a parse action to annotate these elements with their respective types, and these would be retained with each element:

```
a.addParseAction(lambda t: t[0].insert(0, "ELA_TYPE"))
b.addParseAction(lambda t: t[0].insert(0, "ELB_TYPE"))
c.addParseAction(lambda t: t[0].insert(0, "ELC_TYPE"))
```

Parsing with these expressions and dumping the results gives (manually reformatted):

```
- one_seq_expr: [['ELA_TYPE', 'a', '1'], 
                 ['ELB_TYPE', 'b', '2'], 
                 ['ELC_TYPE', 'c', '3'], 
                 ['ELB_TYPE', 'b', '4'], 
                 ['ELA_TYPE', 'a', '5']]
   ... etc. ...
```